# page cut off when resized

Tags: html, css

in my site(sidle page website), if the browser open window is open in full mode it's all OK.

my problem is when I re-size the browser window.

instead of keep the proportions of the page the page appears "cut".

this is one example(there should be 6 orange bullets)

normal mode(open in full mode):
[image]

when I resize the browser window(only 2 bullets appear, if i make the window smaller, less bullets will appear):

[image]

this "page" css is:

```
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: try to put relevant code and post it on http://jsbin.com

Comment: You need to set min-width:your web-site width; to the body element

Comment: I would have post relevant code, if I had any clue about- what it is related to(the site has lot of css lines..) .. @user3657431 min-width:100% and min-height: 100% is already set to the body

Comment: @slash1z try to put this line of code `html, body {width:100%, height:100%}` and `body, .section {min-width:100%; min-height:100%;}.` Let me know if it works.

Comment: did you try to remove `width: 100%; height: 100%;` from class `.section `?

Comment: yes.. you can also try to remove it, noticed weird thing. i am on google chrome.. opened the developer tools, all the site shrinked while i opened it. don't need to resize the window

Comment: strange I checked in FF 29 and I can see all 6 bullet content when the browser is resize.

Comment: checked FF now, it's the same.. and the navigation also not good. in internet explorer 9 its even worse.

Comment: `.section {
  position: relative;
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}` use this code and let me know if its works now

Comment: yes it solved it.. can you also look at the menu(navigation) and the fotter, they are changed on resized, if you can i will upload an image to the post ?

Comment: first lets close this question by accepting the answer; then if you have another question you should ask the question again here.

Comment: okay I've seen the footer section. have some bug

Comment: yes, footer.. facebook like and also the menu, all on resize

Comment: why don't you use a @media-queries to make responsive layout. that way you can easily fix these weird issue.

Comment: i actually did use.. but not for this resolution. can you take a look at the css file? I dont think i used the media-queries correctly.
example: for iphone4- i used "max-width of 320px, and for iphone4 landscape mode i used max width of 480px. how can i measure the screen width when ever a bug related to resize happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem could be solve by  using below line of code. Try to give a `min-height` and `min-width` in given class.

```
.section {   
position: relative;   
/*width: 100%;   
height: 100%;*/   
min-width: 100%;   
min-height: 100%; 
}
```